# signapk.java - hardcode key password during CM11 build

Tags: cyanogenmod

anyone know how to update this code snippet so the platform, media, etc. keys get their password? we're running a CM11 build using make -j32 otapackage. the build crashes b/c one of the processes isn't passing the password. for us to build we can only run make otapackage, which takes hours.

```
/**
* Reads the password from stdin and returns it as a string.
*
* @param keyFile The file containing the private key. Used to prompt the user.
*/
private static String readPassword(File keyFile) {
// TODO: use Console.readPassword() when it's available.
System.out.print("Enter password for " + keyFile + " (password will not be hidden): ");
System.out.flush();

BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
try {
return stdin.readLine();
} catch (IOException ex) {
return null;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the answer:

```
 /**
 * Reads the password from stdin and returns it as a string.
 *
 * @param keyFile The file containing the private key.  Used to prompt the user.
 */
private static String readPassword(File keyFile) {
    try {
    InputStream is = null; 
    InputStreamReader isr = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;   

    // open input stream password.txt for reading purpose.
    is = new FileInputStream("build/tools/signapk/password.txt");

    // create new input stream reader
    isr = new InputStreamReader(is);

    // create new buffered reader
    br = new BufferedReader(isr);

        return br.readLine();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        return null;
    }
}
```